# Explaination for ajax/jquery code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax/jquery on fly for my stuff. I could get working my below code correctly. I read multiple references for both. But being with my own example would grate for me.
Here is my code:

```
var a = JSON.parse(json);       
            $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function(data) 
            {
                $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
            ,async:     true
            ,cache:     false
            ,dataType:  'html'
            ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                FB.XFBML.parse();
                    }
        });      
            });
```

Can some one please examplain job or ajax/jquery at technical level? `$.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function(data)` needs attention.

What if I want to sent multiple values here like $x, $y, $z.
Just `{'myd':$x, $y,$z}` is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a json object `a` in myd variable using a [post request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

The function containing the ajax request `$.ajax({...})` is the `success` function of the post request `$.post('movies_db.php'....)`.

The ajax request, when successful, sends data in the format specified. In this case it is specified as `html`.This html response `data` is being used to replace the contents of the body tag of the document.

`What if I want to sent multiple values here like $x, $y, $z. Just {'myd':$x, $y,$z} is enough?`

Use an array 
`var a = JSON.parse("[x,y,z]"); {'myd':a}` 
**OR** directly set the array as value to myd variable `{'myd':[$x, $y,$z]}`
You have to process this array at server side as it is passed into a single parameter `myd`.

Comment: nice explaination. by the way should it be `{'myd':[$x, $y,$z]}` right? and how one can retrieve x,y,z at server side?

Comment: Yes you are right. If using java on server side, `String[] myd[] = request.getParameterValues("myd[]");` can be used to process the array.

Comment: what if PHP? I am not much sound

Comment: use `json_decode` on the variable `myd` to convert it into php array.

Comment: `{'myd':a}` be replace by `{'x':$x, 'y':$y, 'z':$z}` and server side can be received as `$x= $_POST[x]` if I am not wrong!

Answer (score 1):

```
"What if I want to sent multiple values here like $x, $y, $z. Just {'myd':$x, $y,$z} is enough?"
```

NO. You need to send key value pairs like below:

```
{'myd':$x, 'y': $y, 'z': $z}
```

Why do you need below line? I am not sure. The below line converts json to an object, and you are passing the object as param to ajax call. I think you can pass just the json as it is without parsing, and then decode it on server side to retrieve value:

```
var a = JSON.parse(json);
```

On the server side, you can get an object from json using

```
json_decode($yourGetParam);
```

To convert json to array, add a 2nd param as true:

```
$myarray = json_decode($yourGetParam, true);
```

Comment: he could use `{myd: [$x, $y, $z]}` to post an array of items with the same variable, as long as he can change the code receiving the post to accept an array.  But you're right that JSON.parse shouldn't be needed.  If anything, you do JSON.stringify() on the value object that will be sent.

Comment: @Rajesh:  Thanks . Yes, I can directly send json. But i did when i was not sound about json. Probably both will not make much difference.
can you please add more exaplaination for the code? line by line

Comment: @ps2goat: thanks, can you please let me know how I can parse array values with your convention at server side?

Comment: @Rajesh: any explaination for content below : `var a = JSON.parse(json);  `

Comment: Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx for an explanation

Comment: what are you using on the server side?  I'm only familiar with .NET.

Comment: The url clearly is movies_db.php which means he is using PHP on server side

Answer (score 1):

Okay, not to sound harsh, but **first** let's format your code so we can read it :)

```
var a = JSON.parse(json);
$.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function (data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url.php',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').html(data);
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    });
});
```

So, you're `$.post`ing the data in variable `a` to your `movies_db.php`. The data in `a` is going to show up on your server as `$_POST['myd']`.

If you want to send more values, you need to add more keys to the object you're passing in `{'myd':a}`. For instance:

```
{'myd':a, 'other_data': some_var}
```

Your example was `$x`, `$y`, and `$z`, but this isn't PHP, unless you want to print those values out when the page renders.

Next, when the `$.post` request is finished, it calls the `function (data)` callback, and then it appears that you're sending another `$.ajax` request. In the second request, you're not sending any data, you're just loading `html` by the looks of things. Then you're plugging that HTML into the `body` tag of the document.

#### "AJAX" requests

AJAX means "asynchronous javascript and xml", which is a horrible name for something that can load any type of content. When you call `$.ajax`, you are making an HTTP `GET` request to your server, for which you can pass any data you like. As ps2goat mentioned, you can also specify `POST` as the request type in a "regular" `$.ajax` request.

`$.post` is an HTTP `POST` request, which sends data as well, but in a different way behind the scenes. You generally upload files or post form data this way. The fact that we are using "AJAX" just means we are utilizing the browser's built-in `XMLHTTPRequest` method (again, a terrible name).

Because javascript is asynchronous, you need to specify a callback (your `function`) to handle the response of your call. Obviously, your `function` will be passed the results of the response. If there was an error in the request, it would be handled with an `error` callback, which you haven't specified yet.

I hope that puts you on the right track.

Aaron

Comment: $.ajax can also make posts.  You just specify the option type: "POST".

Comment: @aaronfay: nice! `{'myd':a}` be replace by `{'x':$x, 'y':$y, 'z':$z}` and server side can be received as `$x= $_POST[x]` if I am not wrong!